# What's the proof for the existence of Angels as well as angelic hierarchy?

Tags: angels, thomas-aquinas, systematic-theology, biblical-theology, western-christianity

It's said that most influential medieval work on angelic order was written by Pseudo-Dionysius the Areopagite. How much authority do his works still hold and what's the metaphysical foundation and necessity for the existence of Angels?

Comment: What kind of "proof" are you after? Most Christians would say the fact that angels are talked about in the Bible is all the proof they need.

Answer (score 1):

## [St. Thomas's angelology](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FP.html#TOC03) based on Holy Scriptures

Fr. Garrigou-Lagrange, O.P., discussing St. Thomas Aquinas's sources in [*Reality: A Synthesis of Thomistic Thought*](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=3033) ch. 22, writes:

> It is sometimes thought that the treatise of St. Thomas on the angels is an *a priori* construction, having as its sole foundation the book of Pseudo-Dionysius, called *De coelesti hierarchia*. This is a misconception. **Scripture itself is the foundation on which St. Thomas rests.**

Pohle, [*God the Author of Nature and the Supernatural: A Dogmatic Treatise*](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=3786), pt. 2, ch. 3, §1, Article 1 "Existence & Nature of the Angels":

> The existence of Angels is a truth so obviously founded in Scripture, Tradition, and the teaching of the Church that it seems superfluous to undertake a formal demonstration of it. We therefore merely indicate some of the many Scriptural texts in which it is expressly taught: [Ps. 90:11](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=21&ch=90&l=11-#x); [102:20](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=21&ch=102&l=20-#x); [148:2](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=21&ch=148&l=2-#x); [Matth. 4:11](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=47&ch=4&l=11-#x); [18:10](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=47&ch=18&l=10-#x); [22:30](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=47&ch=22&l=30-#x); [25:31](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=47&ch=25&l=31-#x); [John 1:51](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=50&ch=1&l=51-#x); [Heb. 1:4](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=65&ch=1&l=4-#x).

## Proofs he's not a "pseudo"

Mgr. Darboy famously argued, in the beginning of his [*Œuvres de Saint Denys l'Aréopagite*](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=8066) (1845), that "pseudo-"Dionysius is the actual St. Dionysius that St. Paul baptized in [Acts 17:34](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=51&ch=17&l=34-#x):

> Dionysius the Areopagite and a woman named Damaris and others with them.

Mgr. Darboy has so much data, both [intrinsic and extrinsic evidence](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=8066), in support of his position that the author whom for centuries councils (even heretics!), doctors of the Church, etc., considered authentic is not a "pseudo".

Opponents of his being St. Dionynius base their arguments on one data-point:
According to Stiglmayr's *Catholic Encyclopedia* entry [Dionysius the Pseudo-Areopagite](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/05013a.htm), Stiglmayr & Koch (end of 19th cen.), after Mgr. Darboy (1845), allegedly discovered some Proclus verbatim in *On the Divine Names*! Well, how do they know Proclus (6th cen.) didn't plagiarize St. Dionysius?